# Extract elements from sequences, tuples

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0, c#-to-f#

Say I have this:

```
let coor = seq { ... }
// val coor : seq<int * int> = seq[(12,34); (56, 78); (90, 12); ...]
```

I'm trying to get the value of the first number of the second element in the sequence, in this case 56. Looking at the MSDN Collection API reference, `Seq.nth 1 coor` returns `(56, 78)`, of type `seq <int * int>`. How do I get 56 out of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you go through Tuple article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233200.aspx

A couple of exceptions that might shed some light on the problem:

Function fst is used to access the first element of the tuple:

```
(1, 2) |> fst // returns 1
```

Function snd is used to access the second element

```
(1, 2) |> snd // returns 2
```

In order to extract element from wider tuples you can use following syntax:

```
let _,_,a,_ = (1, 2, 3, 4) // a = 3
```

To use it in various collections (well lambdas that are passed to collection's functions), let's start with following sequence:

```
let s = seq {
        for i in 1..3 do yield i,-i
    }
```

We end up with

```
seq<int * int> = seq [(1, -1); (2, -2); (3, -3)]
```

Let's say we want to extract only the first element (note the arguments of the lambda):

```
s |> Seq.map (fun (a, b) -> a)
```

Or even shorter:

```
s |> Seq.map fst
```

And lets finally go back to your question.

```
s |> Seq.nth 1 |> fst
```

Comment: Thanks dude, took me two hours to find out about fst, snd etc. . .New to F#.

Answer (score 3):

It's a [tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233200.aspx), so you could use the function `fst`;

```
> let value = fst(Seq.nth 1 coor);;
val value : int = 56
```

...or access it via pattern matching;

```
> let value,_ = Seq.nth 1 coor;;    
val value : int = 56
```

Comment: What if I want to modify it and say +1 to it?

Comment: You mean you want a new sequence with that single value replaced?

Comment: Does your sequence happen to be an array?